# Assign photos to location on building floorplan

Tags: geo-location, floor-plan

Whenever I go out on building surveys for work, I take a ton of pictures. I would like to be able to take a picture of the building floorplan and assign the pictures to a location where they were taken sort of like a “GIS-lite” but have not been able to find anything close to this.

The closest I have found was Bluebeam Revu Extreme that lets you assign photos to PDFs but I only want to link to the original photo location since adding the photos into the PDFs causes the file size to balloon ridiculously.

I would like open source but am willing to pay for closed source software if it does what I want.